# How to remove the extra space between two span elements?

Tags: html, css, margin

[image]

I want to remove the extra space between these two elements. I tried but couldn't do it.
Is this a problem of margin collapsing?

How can this be solved? How can I remove that extra space?

**Here is my HTML and CSS:**

```css
body {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
}

#output {
  font-family: roboto light;
  color: #A4C639;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#grade {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}

#max {
  color: black;
}

#percentage {
  background: #A4C639;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <i>
    <span id="grade">Your grade :</span>
    <span id="total">524</span>
    <span id="max">/725</span>
    <center><h1><span id="percentage">72.28%</span></h1></center>
  </i>
</div>
```

Comment: Which two span elements, specifically? You have four.

Comment: But one of the span is the one with id="percentage" and I think the other three are in a single line.

Comment: @nikhil did you thought about compressed html file?

Comment: Also I'm not sure that you're using the `<i>` tag correctly. Perhaps consider the `<b>` tag, instead, if you need that semantic differentiation.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if you have the wrong title - your `h1` is what is causing the space between the text and the percentage box.  To remove try this:

```
#output h1 {margin-top:0; padding-top:0;}
```

If it actually the spans you are talking about then you need to remove any white space that is between them - See the other answers for this

Comment: you're right dude! The <h1> is causing the trouble. Your solution worked but I changed the value of margin-top to 25px. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @nikhil `h1` is a block element and it has a default margin-top which is not zero.

Comment: Ok @KingKing, I've edited my comment, 0 I refered is the one in #output h1 {margin-top:0; padding-top:0;} given by Pete.

Answer (score 48):

Whitespace characters between HTML elements create a new text block, which is displayed as a space between the elements.

Remove all the whitespacing between the elements to get rid of it:

```
<span id="total"></span><span id="max"></span>
```

Alternatively, you can fill the whitespaces with a comment block:

```
<span id="total"></span><!--
--><span id="max"></span>
```

Comment: The comment trick is clever, I like it. Additionally, if you get eslint errors if using the comment approach, you can add a `<!-- eslint-disable -->` above

Answer (score 24):

Put the `<span>` tags on the same line without any space between them.

Comment: It didn't change buddy

Comment: Are you sure you are not putting extra space character inside `#max`?

Comment: Ahh... It was hard to tell which span you were talking about.

Answer (score 1):

That's some weird behavior of span elements in HTML.
If the first span has style `text-decoration: underline;` then one extra space will be underlined also.

I solved it by changing `span` to `div` and applying `display: inline-block` to divs.

Comment: That's the solution

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but I would have done this differently - the original HTML is combining display and semantic elements together ( with the italic, H1 and center tags).

I would do the HTML like this:

```
<div id="output">
  <span class="grade">
    Your grade :
    <span class="total">123</span>/<span class="max">777</span>
    <div class="percentage">23.45%</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

And the CSS like so:

```
#output {
    font-style:italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-family : roboto light;
    color : #A4C639;
    font-size : 30px;
    width: 250px;
}

.grade {
    font-size : 25px;
    color: black;
}

.total {
    color : #A4C639;
}

.max {
    margin-left:0;
}

.percentage {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
    background : #A4C639;
    color : #FFFFFF;
    padding : 15px;
    border-radius : 15px;
}
```

This gives you what you were after but the style and layout was done totally in the CSS markup.

If you want to see it in action try this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/justin_thomas/P6wmJ/19/

It is usually much better to separate your style from your content and semantics. It will make things easier if you ever need to change the layout and so on.

Answer (score -2):

try `i{font-size:0}#output span{font-size:30px;}` in your css

Comment: Please don't. Its very hacky and not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: don't understand what the problem with this approach @jsalonen.. can you please give some hint why you not prefer this approach.

Comment: For once it will mess up all your other CSS with `i` tags. Also it does not fix the root cause. For example if you copy&paste the text from the HTML it will still likely contain the extra whitespace.