# How would I remove the space between my menu options?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about removing the black line between my menu options when using the hover function in CSS?

https://jsfiddle.net/jameskelly/3ejsu7gx/2/

```css
   a:hover {
     background-color: #ebebeb;
     font-color: black;
   }
   
   /* Style the navbar */
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  }

/* Navbar links */
#navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  content-align: center;    
}

#navbar current {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  content-align: center;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <current href="index.html">Home</current>
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="services.html">Services</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the extra space between two span elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689794/how-to-remove-the-extra-space-between-two-span-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For navigation menus, using unordered lists is the easiest way to maintain styling. I changed the `div` to a `ul`  with `display:flex` for the layout.

```css
/* Style the navbar */

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}


/* Navbar links */

li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px;
}

current a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  content-align: center;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li>
    <current><a href="index.html">Home</a></current>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use links in menu items and have spaces between them.
Put the menu items on one line, and in general, try to use [unnumbered lists](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_menu) as menu.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <current href="index.html">Home</current><a href="about.html">About</a><a href="services.html">Services</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use display flex.

Just add this two properties in the navbar div:

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  }
```